# Updating initial feature class within for loop using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a forested area, that suffered different disturbances over multiple years. Each year, disturbance data was collected on different forest extend and some disturbances can overlap (beetle infestation or clear-cut).

My goal is to clean and summarize the dataset, i.e. unify the extent and allow the forest area to be disturbed only once over my time period. 
Simply, I wish to clip the disturbance data to the available forest area in current year, and update the extend of forest cover after every disturbance.

I am trying to apply `arcpy` to automate the process.

**Pseudocode**:

- read forest area & list yearly disturbances
- create for loop to loop through list of disturbances

  - clip disturbance by available forest
  - update available forest by erasing the disturbance from current forest cover
  - do the same for next disturbance

I thought this could be fairy simple to do. However, my script either return empty dataset, erase the initial forest or says "that output and input data equals".

My desired **output** is the set of cleaned (not overlapping disturbances limited on forest) disturbances. I am trying to automate the process, as I have 3 different disturbances types over multiple years, together 18 disturbances featureclasses.

**How to update the forest polygon and spatially restrict every disturbance?**

```
import arcpy
import os

# Allow files to overwrite
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Define directories
path = "U:\\project\\analyzed"
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(path, "analyzed.gdb")
outWD = os.path.join(path, "cleaned.gdb")
aoi = "aoi_fin_03"

# Read all disturbance data
disturbLs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Intersect available forest with disturbances in each year,
# update forest cover 
for dist in disturbLs:
    # Clip the disturbance to forest extend
    outClip = os.path.join(outWD, dist)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(dist, aoi, outClip)

    # Update available forest cover by erasing current disturbance
    updAoi = "in_memory\layer" + aoi
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(aoi, updAoi)
    arcpy.Erase_analysis(updAoi, outClip, aoi)

#Delete in memory files to avoid the lock
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
```

Comment: How many different disturbance datasets do you have?

Comment: I have beetle infestation, clear cut and windthorow, varying in years. In total 18 feature classes, which I order using this script: `disturbLs.sort(key=lambda x:[int(x.split('_')[1]),x.split('_')[0]])` (not shown in example to keep it simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my problem was that for some features `clip` tool generated empty output. This lead to to further generate empty `forest` class etc.

So here, I check if the count of rows in a feature class and than run my loop only on those features:

```
if arcpy.management.GetCount(dist)[0] > "0":
    print dist
```

The whole code:

```
import arcpy
import os

# Allow files to overwrite
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Define directories
path = "U:\\projects\\analyzed"
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(path, "trySubset.gdb")
outWD = os.path.join(path, "cleanedSub.gdb")
aoi = "aoi_fin_03"


# Read all disturbance data
disturbLs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# For loop
for dist in disturbLs:

    # Check if the feature class is not empty
    if arcpy.management.GetCount(dist)[0] > "0":

        # clip disturbance to forest area, 
        # save the output
        outClipDist = os.path.join(outWD, dist)
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(dist, aoi, outClipDist)

        #  save the updated forest to verify it
        updAOI = os.path.join(outWD, "aoi_" + dist)

        # Erase the current disturbance from the available forest
        arcpy.Erase_analysis(aoi, outClipDist, updAOI)

        # update the forest cover to use at the beginning of for loop
        aoi = updAOI
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be oversimplifying the problem but a single Union and Select could work:

1. Union stands and all disturbances
2. Select where FID_stands>-1 and all disturbances FID<0
3. Export selection

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! However, my forest does not consist of stands. It is derived from the raster forest cover data and as such I have only 1 forest polygon. That's why I need to do clips or intersections, and erasing. Do you think that the logic of my pseudocode is correct?

Comment: It should work with only one forest polygon, does not matter

Comment: Hi BERA, I have tried your approach. It seems interesting, but pretty complicated: I have 18 disturbances in total, which makes to manually select 18 fields in a query. Also, as an optput I expect to get unique clean disturbances, again 18 in total. Those I would like to later group by year, and calculate sum of yearly non overlapping disturbances.

Comment: You can construct the Query using arcpy and listfields , no need to do it manually